# PHP: $_SESSION is shared on multiple computers on same network

Tags: php, session, networking, public

I'm using `$_SESSION` for keeping track of logins at my website.

The website should be used on my school which is a public wifi. But for some reason, when someone logs in using on the website, then everyone else will get logged in too.

I understood that `$_SESSION` works with cookies, and therefore this should not happen? Basically, new machines accessing the website, sometimes is logged in as users, which has logged in on another machine...

Is it something to do with my host? There is no problems with other websites at all. So it's either my code or the host's setup.

Any help to troubleshoot this is appreciated.

Comment: some code would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I've used sessions for years without problems, but this host seems to not like the same code..

Anyhow, i switched to use login-cookies. Every user get a cookie when logged in, with a random char of a length of 50. This char is then stored in the database, with the user id.

That works fine. :)